# Entity Framework 6 Oracle and Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

I am hitting an issue with Oracle and EF6 optimistic concurrency.
I have an update trigger which increments a row_version field and have registered this field as a ConcurrencyToken and as being DatabaseGenerated (Computed)

The issue I am seeing is that the update query has a row count of 1 when the query actually hasn't updated the row (row_version was changed out of band)

I am putting together a reproduction now and will update once on github...

```
[Column("ROW_VERSION"), ConcurrencyCheck, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int? RowVersion { get; set; }
```

The query going over the wire is a little quirky:

```
declare
     "ROW_VERSION" number(10,0);
     "ROWID" char(18);
begin
update
     "DB"."TEST"
     set "NAME" = 'John Smith'
where (("ID" = 1) and ("ROW_VERSION" = 1))      
returning
"ROW_VERSION",
     "ROWID" into
"ROW_VERSION",
     "ROWID";
open '' /* :p4 */ for select

"ROW_VERSION" as "ROW_VERSION",
     "ROWID" as "ROWID" 
from dual;
end;
```

When I try to run this query manually in SQL Developer it causes an error:

**Error Message**
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 6:
PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2602]
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

When executed via Entity Framework no errors are reported

**Dependencies:**

- Oracle 12c
- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.1.2400

**UPDATE**
I have uploaded a simple solution which reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/Certegy/Concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround to solve this bug.  When the update **fails** silently the 'Computed' fields are not updated to their new values... instead they are set to **null**.

So the solution is to manually inspect the computed fields and **manually** throw the DbUpdateConcurrencyException if they are null.

I hope the underlining EF bug is addressed. If someone knows where to lodge the bug report please let me know!